# jQuery ajax doesn't work on url without www

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, jquery

The jQuery ajax script below doesn't work on my site if `url` is without www. I checked Firebug and it doesn't send the ajax call.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mysite.com/beta/products.php",
        data: "page_type=index&sort=relevancerank&CartId=<?php echo $CartId;?>&HMAC=<?php echo $HMAC;?>",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $('#content-holder').html(msg);

        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("An error occurred while updating. Try again in a while");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming the calling document URL is referenced as "mysite.com", or "subdomain.mysite.com"? The XMLHttpRequest object (the engine that powers jQuery Ajax calls) can not perform "cross-domain" requests. A subdomain (e.g. 'www') qualifies. Make sure your requests are to the same subdomain.

Comment: exactly!. Actually my ajax call worked  when i used www in the url. it didn't worked in without www. After looking @ your comment, i checked my ajax call and i given url parameter with www. Thanks!

Comment: If you provide relative URL like: "www.your-site.com/some/some/..." instead "/some/some/..." AJAX not work when you call "your-site.com/some/some/..." because don't perform "cross-domain" requests. Use relative URL in your AJAX and will work on WWW and without WWW.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to provide an absolute URL, you can simply provide a [relative](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.3) one, and it will work regardless if the your page is loaded with the *www.* subdomain or not:

```
//...
    type: "POST",
    url: "/beta/products.php",
//...
```

Comment: i agree with you. but in some cases, if we carry this ajax call in our header page also when there is a htaccess redirection we've to stick with absoulte url.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server redirecting to the "www" domain possibly?   This is probably just the same-origin policy preventing your outer page from accessing a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

www. is just a naming convention - ajax will load on any address that can be looked up via dns, or it will work on an ip address as long as there is a server to respond to the request.

BUT - your page location and the ajax request need to be in the same domain for security reasons. To get round this restriction, you need to use something called JSONP

Comment: I'm having problems with this. If I access my site without the "www" the same-origin policy problem arises. Now I have to fix this because all my ajax calss are done with the absolute url.