# javascript scripts won't work and events won't fire without www

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, web

Before I start, let me say that using a .htaccess that adds www doesn't solves completely the problem :-( it works "most of the times" (it won't work only when in front of a client)

I have my portfolio website. If I launch it with www.mysite.com, the javascript runs fine.
If I launch it with mysite.com javascript won't always run, and certain events won't fire. For example I load with an ajax call my portfolio.
The page I load has an image with an onload event attached.
The onload fires only when the site is called with www

The weirdest thing is that a redirect with .htaccess doesn't always solve the problem, it reduces the occurrence and makes it random :-/

Could somebody explain me why this happens? I've had similar issues in the past and never got at the end of it.

Thanks a million for your help

Comment: We'd need a lot more detail -- of the config, of exactly what goes wrong when it doesn't work, of attempts to figure out what the problem is, ...

Comment: if you are using absolute url's (with protocol and domain) and the subdomain doesn't match then it is a cross domain ajax call/ Need far more details

Comment: check out this thread,,,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555580/jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-on-url-without-www